# Dynamically navigate works with big delay

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

In my app, I'm trying to make dynamically redirecting for root page ("/"). The result of this expression is changing correctly based on AuthObject for which we are waiting. But redirecting is happen with 5-10 seconds delay.

But it only happens when we have first visit in my app, so to imitate my error you have to copy the link from codesandbox (from browser where we can find result of app) and open in new tab with removing added url (for example: https://b0u91.csb.app/#/firstPage should be https://b0u91.csb.app/#/).

In my app I'm using mobx to share global state and newest React Router v6.

Code responsible for render route paths:

```
    <Routes>
      {authStore.getStatus() === "complete" &&
        Pages.PAGES(authStore)
          .filter((page) => page.auth)
          .map((page) => (
            <Route
              key={page.to + page.index}
              path={page.to}
              element={page.children()}
            />
          ))}
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          <Navigate
            to={
              authStore.getStatus() === "complete" &&
              Pages.PAGES(authStore).filter((page) => page.auth).length
                ? Pages.PAGES(authStore).filter((page) => page.auth)[0].to
                : "/"
            }
            replace
          />
        }
      />
    </Routes>
```

Pages:

```js
export class Pages {
  static PAGES = (authStore) => [
    {
      index: 0,
      to: "/firstPage",
      label: "First Page",
      children: () => <div>FIRST PAGE</div>,
      auth: authStore.getFirstPageAuth()
    },
...
  ];
}
```

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-bird-b0u91?file=/src/App.js)

In this example (like in real app) I have a lot of these errors in console

```
index.js:1 
        
       Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside `useEffect`, but `useEffect` either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

So, there was a big mistake in logic because our router was redirecting us from "/" to "/" over and over again when we were waiting for a response.

I changed a little code to fix it:

```
...
      {Pages.PAGES(authStore).filter((page) => page.auth).length && (
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <Navigate
              to={Pages.PAGES(authStore).filter((page) => page.auth)[0].to}
              replace
            />
          }
        />
      )}
...
```

Comment: What is the issue? What are you asking? Seems the code is doing exactly what you coded it to do, conditionally rendering routes and/or redirecting based on the `authStore.getStatus() === "complete"` condition.

Comment: But redirecting happens after some seconds, please check example on codesandbox, also I updated post.

Comment: I did, it seems to work as you coded it. The redirect happens after `authStore.getStatus()` updates. What are you expecting to occur?

Comment: Can you open it in new tab (it's important): https://b0u91.csb.app/#/ ? And please look when you will be redirecting to /firstPage (When list be rendered (that's sign when we got response)). In my case it was 7 seconds right now.

Comment: I did. So it is the additional "delay" that is the issue? This seems more an issue with your state than react-router.

Comment: I think it's looped with redirecting because when we go into / then app is redirecting to /. That was stupid from my side.

Comment: Yes, that was the case of this errors, In a minute I will add solution to my post. Thanks for your help